# MySQL- Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have got an old site that has recently been displaying an error which is weird as its been untouched for some time. I get the following:

```
Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8
```

What is the cause of this and how should I fix it?

It is a PHP/MySQL site.

Comment: How do you mean with `jump to row 0`? Also show the error that you get.

Comment: What gives you this error? Does it appear on the HTML of the website or in some error log? I would suggest you to first locate from which point of your PHP code and which SQL query this error comes from. Then gives us some further details on those code lines if you are still unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this error typically stems from a code segment like the following:

```
// You probably have some code similar to this
$var = mysql_result( $result, 0, 'column_name');
```

Where either the query fails or the column doesn't exist. Check that `$result` is a valid MySQL resource to make sure that the SQL is valid, then make sure you're actually getting results from the database before trying to call `mysql_result`.

Or, better yet, using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of manually fetching every column value (if you have multiple columns returned from the query).

Comment: Interesting that I have several years old code and the aforementioned error suddenly appeared. Using `mysql_fetch_array` indeed fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try analysing the result before fetching it.
If result is empty, skip fetching.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
if (!$result || !mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    die('Empty set.');
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Cheers guys - sorted a ID was incorrect in query as it had been changed by someone (not me lol)