# Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index

Tags: php, mysql, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL- Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342054/mysql-unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysql-result-index)

I am getting mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 error. I don't know what's wrong with the function below

```
function update_counter($post_id){
    global $wpdb;       
    $query = "SELECT view_count FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."advert_views WHERE postid = $post_id";
    if(@$query_run = mysql_query($query)){
        $count = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'view_count' );
        $count_inc = $count + 1;
        $query_update = "UPDATE ".$wpdb->prefix."advert_views SET view_count = $count_inc WHERE postid = $post_id";
        if(@$query_update_run = mysql_query($query_update)){
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }
}
```

---

Okay I modified the function with below code and error gone. Just refer other questions. but I can't understand logic properly. Can anyone help me to understand this logic where what actually > 0 does?

```
function update_counter($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT view_count FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."advert_views WHERE postid = $post_id";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {
        $count = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'view_count' );
        $count_inc = $count + 1;
        $query_update = "UPDATE ".$wpdb->prefix."advert_views SET view_count = $count_inc WHERE postid = $post_id";
        if(@$query_update_run = mysql_query($query_update)){
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your query did not return any rows?

Comment: May be but as I am not so master in all these so sometime don't understand the relation of those questions with mine

Comment: I think the query runs, but selects an empty set of rows. That way mysql_query runs and returns a resource, but `mysql_result` fails because row `0` does not exist. When you check that the number of selected rows is greater than `0`, you protect against this case.

Comment: You mean in reality there is no 0 row ( means there is at least one row ) and that is why it was resulting error? and with grater than zero will make condition true as db has one row. Is that something like this?

Comment: Off topic but important: The `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered **obsolete and insecure**. They are in the process of deprecation and will thus eventually be removed from PHP. The PHP manual recommends stopping using them immediately and switching to either the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Comment: Yes, it results in the error when no rows are selected.