# MySQL PHP SELECT throwing up an error?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, comments

I am trying to make a comment section on my hand made site, using PHP and MySQL. I have got the comments stored in my database, but when I try to SELECT them my site throws up this error,

> mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a9210109/public_html/comments.php on line 16

My code so far is below

```
    <?php
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $mysql_host = "";
    $mysql_database = "";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_password = "";
    mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
    @mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE comments (comment VARCHAR(255), time VARCHAR(255));";
    mysql_query($CreateTable);
    $UseComment = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('$comment')";
    mysql_query($UseComment);
    $SelectComments = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $comments = mysql_query($SelectComments);
    $num=mysql_numrows($comments);
    $variable=mysql_result($comments,$i,"comment");
    mysql_close();
    ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('hidden');">Show/Hide Comments</a>
    <?php
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {
    $comment=mysql_result($comments,$i,"comment");
    echo "<div id='hidden' style='display:none'><h3>$comment</h3></div>";
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
 $num=mysql_numrows($comments);
```

to

```
$num=mysql_num_rows($comments);
```

the right syntax is `mysql_num_rows` not `mysql_numrows`

Comment: @user1909695 if you found the answer useful than mark it as correct, so other users can refer it.

Answer (score 1):

$i is not set in the first php part:

```
$variable=mysql_result($comments,$i,"comment");
```

Fix the above!

Comment: wait: should I remove "comment" because another user has just told me that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342054/mysql-unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysql-result-index).
Regarding with your code, you did not have `$i` before the line 16 which caused the error:

```
$variable=mysql_result($comments,$i,"comment");
```

You should check if there is any result before issuing `mysql_result`:

```
$SelectComments = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$comments = mysql_query($SelectComments);
if( $num = mysql_num_rows($comments) ){
    $variable = mysql_result($comments, 0, "comment");
}
```

I would personally write a COUNT query to get the total number of comments:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM comments';
$comments = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments);
$totalComments = $row['total'];
```

In this case, you don't need to check with `mysql_num_rows()` because the COUNT query will definitely return one result "0" or whatever.

Comment: ah ok thank you, should I remove "comment" or simply define $i before?

Comment: what should I do, just define $i as 0?

Comment: @user1909695, you're welcome. At least, you should accept one of the answers. They are trying to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are no records in data base.

$UseComment = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('$comment')";  is wrong.

Change it as

$UseComment = "INSERT INTO comments(comment) VALUES ('$comment')";

Thanks.